# ReportViewer Scroll Bars not visible on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: reporting-services

Scroll bars are visible in chrome but not in Internet Explorer 11

I have tried debugging and inspecting element to find in the DOM where exactly are the scroll bars. Didn't get any luck

Answer (score 0):

found a suggestion on this link :-

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5e03c026-7359-4c0a-8c12-97dac9a2eb9c/reportviewer-2012-scroll-bars?forum=sqlreportingservices

At very bottom of the link this guy named - Palanichamy suggested to put below code in the css file.

```
#VisibleReportContentctl32_ctl09{
     position : absolute;
     _:-ms-fullscreen, :root;
}
```

And other guy on the same link suggested where that file exactly located : 
To the following file on my report server:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportManager\Styles\ReportServices.css

But I still didn't get any luck. So the last thing I tried is I copied the code in whatever report you are trying to run its name.aspx file and in the header tag I created a new style tag and then found out the correct id of the element by inspecting code.

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<style type="text/css">
    #VisibleReportContentrvAdHocReport_ctl09 {
        position : absolute;
        _:-ms-fullscreen, :root;
    }

</style>
```